# Angular 2: closing tr-tag

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-template

Why is this not working? I get an unclosed-tag error for "tr" in the browsers console.

```
Error: Template parse errors:
Unexpected closing tag "tr". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag.
```

But as far I can see there should be no unclosed tags.
I open tr at the very beginning and close it at last. So the close-open in ngIf should work in any case.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: "parent",

template: `
<table border=1>
<tr>

<ng-container *ngFor="let k of [1,2,3,4]">
 <td>test</td>
 <ng-container *ngIf="true">
    </tr><tr>
 </ng-container>
</ng-container>

</tr>
</table>
`
})

export class ParentComponent {}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You have a table row open-close the wrong way around in your `<ng-container>`

```
</tr><tr>
```

Should be

```
<tr></tr>
```

Comment: That would nest a `<tr></tr>` inside of the existing `<tr>...</tr>`. Eg: `<tr><td>test</td><tr></tr></tr>` I think if the second contain evaluates true the OP is trying to create a *second* row, but only one otherwise. Not a nested one.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Good spot. Yes I have misunderstood the code. In that case OP should move this code outside of the original `<tr>`. 

`<ng-container *ngIf="true">
    <tr></tr>
 </ng-container>`

Comment: I believe that template needs to be valid HTML or OP will hit a parse error anyway. The code has to be restructured so that the </tr> isn't nested inside the container.

Comment: Why?? The loop starts with an opened <tr>. In any possible application it gets closed and open again. And at the end it gets closed.